# Is it okay if I leave Ubuntu permanently on suspend?

Tags: suspend

There's an issue on my laptop that's making it boot *very* slow. I haven't figured what the problem is yet, but meanwhile, is it okay if I leave Ubuntu on a permanent suspend (24X7)?

Will that my damage my hardware or Ubuntu's performance. In other words, will the prolonged usage damage my hardware, and is a proper shutdown necessary every now and then for Ubuntu to function properly?

(My battery is already dead, so I have no power saving issues as of now).

Comment: Din't think it will damage anything, besides, there seems to be no other choice.

Comment: If you have no battery, and you rely only on suspend, you will eventually lose data. As soon as power is interrupted in this case, the machine will power off. Anything left in RAM will be gone, and anything in process of being written to disk will be corrupted. If your battery is truly dead, I'd recommend replacing it asap, and only powering the laptop using a UPS until you do.